# Group hashtables together based on commonalities (direct and indirect)

Tags: powershell

I have a set of accounts in an array. Here's a simple example:

```
# ------------
# Example data
# ------------

$accounts = @(
    @{
        AccountName = "john.smith"
        DisplayName = "John Smith"
        Email = "jsmith@example.com"
        Id = 1
    }
    @{
        AccountName = "richard.wilson"
        DisplayName = "Richard Wilson"
        Email = "rwilson@example.com"
        Id = 2
    }
    @{
        AccountName = "em_eng2013"
        DisplayName = "EM Engineering #2013"
        Email = "jsmith@example.com"
        Id = 3
    }
    @{
        AccountName = "em_eng1985"
        DisplayName = "EM Engineering #1985"
        Email = "rwilson@example.com"
        Id = 4
    }
    @{
        AccountName = "victoria.jacobs"
        DisplayName = "Victoria Jacobs"
        Email = "vjacobs@example.com"
        Id = 5
    }
    @{
        AccountName = "victoria.jacobs"
        DisplayName = "VJacobs"
        Email = "c_vjacobs@uni.example.com"
        Id = 6
    }
    @{
        AccountName = "i474"
        DisplayName = "John Smith"
        Email = "i474@internal.example.com"
        Id = 7
    }
    @{
        AccountName = "interactive.i474"
        DisplayName = "Interactive Console"
        Email = "i474@internal.example.com"
        Id = 8
    }
)
```

#### Goal

Group related accounts together and find the total number of unique people these accounts belong to. For example, just looking at it visually, you can see that the person `Victoria Jacobs` has 2 accounts, as accounts with `ID 5` and `ID 6` share the same account name.

Here's an example of the desired output. `$people`'s keys could be anything really -- a GUID, an incremented `int`. At the moment I am only interested in the total # of keys so we have a rough idea how many parental/identity containers we need to make for these accounts.

```
# --------------
# Desired output
# --------------

$people = @{
    <#
        Account 1 is related to account 3 because they share the same email
        Account 7 is related to account 1 because they share the same display name
        Account 8 is related to account 7 because they share the same email
    #>
    "1" = @(
        @{
            AccountName = "john.smith"
            DisplayName = "John Smith"
            Email = "jsmith@example.com"
            Id = 1
        }
        @{
            AccountName = "em_eng2013"
            DisplayName = "EM Engineering #2013"
            Email = "jsmith@example.com"
            Id = 3
        }
        @{
            AccountName = "i474"
            DisplayName = "John Smith"
            Email = "i474@internal.example.com"
            Id = 7
        }
        @{
            AccountName = "interactive.i474"
            DisplayName = "Interactive Console"
            Email = "i474@internal.example.com"
            Id = 8
        }
    )
    <#
        These accounts shared the same email
    #>
    "2" = @(
        @{
            AccountName = "richard.wilson"
            DisplayName = "Richard Wilson"
            Email = "rwilson@example.com"
            Id = 2
        }
        @{
            AccountName = "em_eng1985"
            DisplayName = "EM Engineering #1985"
            Email = "rwilson@example.com"
            Id = 4
        }
    )
    <#
        These accounts share the same account name
    #>
    "3" = @(
        @{
            AccountName = "victoria.jacobs"
            DisplayName = "Victoria Jacobs"
            Email = "vjacobs@example.com"
            Id = 5
        }
        @{
            AccountName = "victoria.jacobs"
            DisplayName = "VJacobs"
            Email = "c_vjacobs@uni.example.com"
            Id = 6
        }
    )
}
```

#### Problem

Accounts can be related directly by a matching `AccountName`, `DisplayName`, or `Email` value. Accounts could be indirectly related if one relationship leads to another. In this example, Account A is directly related to Account B and Account B is directly related to Account C, therefore, Account A is indirectly related to Account C. All 3 accounts are grouped together.

```
Account A                     Account B                     Account C
---------                     ---------                     ---------
AccountName: bob.jones        AccountName: bjones1          AccountName: robertjones
DisplayName: Bob Jones        DisplayName: Robert Jones ==> DisplayName: Robert Jones
Email: bjones@example.com ==> Email: bjones@example.com     Email: highlandteam@example.com
```

#### What have you tried?

I've gotten accounts with matching attribute values into 3 hashtables, a `$LookupByAccountName`, `$LookupByDisplayName`, and `$LookupByEmail`. This solves finding the direct relationships. My mind starts to turn to mush though if I attempt to find indirect relationships, like in the above example. I encounter issues during recursion where infinite switching could occur, (e.g Find all accounts related to A, (finds B). Find all accounts related to B (finds A) -- loop).

With passing persisted state data into functions and doing a bunch of conditional checks I am having difficulty visualizing what I need to be writing. I want to step back and ask -- is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you correctly, you want to combine any of these 4 properties together if the accounts are either directly or indirectly related. I assume that you want to join them with a comma, please correct me if I'm wrong. Perhaps this will achieve your desired result.

Please note I changed the `$accounts` variable to `$accountlist` as it's very easy to typo one way or the other. It's a best practice to name the variables like this vs plural/singular.

```
$tracker = [System.Collections.Generic.list[PSCustomObject]]::new()

foreach($account in $accountlist)
{
    if($match = $tracker | where {$_.accountname -match $account.accountname -or 
                                  $_.displayname -match $account.displayname -or
                                  $_.email -match $account.email})
    {
        foreach($category in 'accountname','displayname','email','id')
        {
            if($match.$category -notmatch $account.$category)
            {
                $match.$category = $match.$category,$account.$category -join ', '
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $tracker.Add($account)
    }
}

"There are {0} distinct users" -f $tracker.count
```

Outputs

```
There are 3 distinct users
```

The contents of `$tracker` in the end

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
Email                          jsmith@example.com, i474@internal.example.com                                                                                                                  
DisplayName                    John Smith, EM Engineering #2013, Interactive Console                                                                                                          
Id                             1, 3, 7, 8                                                                                                                                                     
AccountName                    john.smith, em_eng2013, i474, interactive.i474                                                                                                                 
Email                          rwilson@example.com                                                                                                                                            
DisplayName                    Richard Wilson, EM Engineering #1985                                                                                                                           
Id                             2, 4                                                                                                                                                           
AccountName                    richard.wilson, em_eng1985                                                                                                                                     
Email                          vjacobs@example.com, c_vjacobs@uni.example.com                                                                                                                 
DisplayName                    Victoria Jacobs, VJacobs                                                                                                                                       
Id                             5, 6                                                                                                                                                           
AccountName                    victoria.jacobs
```

To make it easier to visualize each you can do something like this

```
$tracker | foreach {
    "Combined account`n$('-'*20)"
    $_
    "`n"
}
```

Which outputs

```
Combined account
--------------------

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
Email                          jsmith@example.com, i474@internal.example.com                                                                                                                  
DisplayName                    John Smith, EM Engineering #2013, Interactive Console                                                                                                          
Id                             1, 3, 7, 8                                                                                                                                                     
AccountName                    john.smith, em_eng2013, i474, interactive.i474                                                                                                                 


Combined account
--------------------
Email                          rwilson@example.com                                                                                                                                            
DisplayName                    Richard Wilson, EM Engineering #1985                                                                                                                           
Id                             2, 4                                                                                                                                                           
AccountName                    richard.wilson, em_eng1985                                                                                                                                     


Combined account
--------------------
Email                          vjacobs@example.com, c_vjacobs@uni.example.com                                                                                                                 
DisplayName                    Victoria Jacobs, VJacobs                                                                                                                                       
Id                             5, 6                                                                                                                                                           
AccountName                    victoria.jacobs
```

**Edit:**

So there were a couple of problems in the previous suggestion. One I noticed was the original `$accountlist` was getting changed as a side effect. It seems the variable `$account` was a reference to the original object. This could be overcome by creating a new object like `$account | select *` however there are two other issues. The test array is a bunch of hashtables and it probably best to have PSCustomObjects. It's likely you will be importing CSV or retreiving the data in another fashion. The difference can be seen in these two examples.

*Hashtables*

```
@(
    @{
        AccountName = "victoria.jacobs"
        DisplayName = "Victoria Jacobs"
        Email = "vjacobs@example.com"
        Id = 5
    }
    @{
        AccountName = "richard.wilson"
        DisplayName = "Richard Wilson"
        Email = "rwilson@example.com"
        Id = 2
    }
)

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
Email                          vjacobs@example.com                                                                                                                                            
DisplayName                    Victoria Jacobs                                                                                                                                                
Id                             5                                                                                                                                                              
AccountName                    victoria.jacobs                                                                                                                                                
Email                          rwilson@example.com                                                                                                                                            
DisplayName                    Richard Wilson                                                                                                                                                 
Id                             2                                                                                                                                                              
AccountName                    richard.wilson
```

*PSCustomObjects*

```
@'
"Email","DisplayName","Id","AccountName"
"vjacobs@example.com","Victoria Jacobs","5","victoria.jacobs"
"rwilson@example.com","Richard Wilson","2","richard.wilson"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

Email               DisplayName     Id AccountName    
-----               -----------     -- -----------    
vjacobs@example.com Victoria Jacobs 5  victoria.jacobs
rwilson@example.com Richard Wilson  2  richard.wilson
```

If your data is actually in that format, you can simply convert each of them like this

```
$accountlist = $accountlist | foreach {[pscustomobject]$_}

Email                     DisplayName          Id AccountName     
-----                     -----------          -- -----------     
vjacobs@example.com       Victoria Jacobs       5 victoria.jacobs 
rwilson@example.com       Richard Wilson        2 richard.wilson
```

Final issue is the fact that the order of processing can adjust the results if indirect accounts were compared after the matching account was processed.

Here is my updated solution. We simply build a temporary tracker similar to the previous one as well as a "related IDs" tracker. Along the way we need to remove/update previous entries that later turn out to be related. Thus the final `$related` variable contain each grouping of IDs

```
$tracker = [System.Collections.Generic.list[object]]::new()
$related = [System.Collections.Generic.list[string]]::new()

foreach($account in $accountlist)
{
    if($match = $tracker | where {$_.accountname -match "^$($account.accountname)$" -or 
                                  $_.displayname -match "^$($account.displayname)$" -or
                                  $_.email -match "^$($account.email)$"} | select id)
    {
        if($match.count -gt 1)
        {
            $exclude = '({0})' -f ($match.id -join '|')
            $combine = $related | where {$_ -match $exclude}
            $related = $related | where {$_ -notmatch $exclude}
            $combine += $account.id
            $related += $combine -join ','
        }
        else
        {
            $related = $related | where {$_ -notmatch $match.id}
            $related += $account.id,$match.id -join ','
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $related += $account.id
        $tracker.Add(($account | select *))
    }
}

"There are {0} distinct users" -f $related.count  

There are 3 distinct users
```

`$related` contains

```
4,2
6,5
3,8,7,1
```

We can continuing processing based on these groupings if needed. I know your original request was just to know how many distinct users/accounts there are, but for completeness I wanted to provide a way to utilize them. A simple way to group them would be to use a hashtable.

```
$relatedaccounts = [hashtable]::new()

$related | foreach {
    $idmatch = '({0})' -f ($_ -split ',' -join '|')
    $relatedaccounts[$_] = $accountlist | where id -match $idmatch
}

$relatedaccounts

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
4,2                            {@{Email=rwilson@example.com; DisplayName=Richard Wilson; Id=2; AccountName=richard.wilson}, @{Email=rwilson@example.com; DisplayName=EM Engineering #1985; ...
3,8,7,1                        {@{Email=jsmith@example.com; DisplayName=EM Engineering #2013; Id=3; AccountName=em_eng2013}, @{Email=i474@internal.example.com; DisplayName=John Smith; Id=...
6,5                            {@{Email=vjacobs@example.com; DisplayName=Victoria Jacobs; Id=5; AccountName=victoria.jacobs}, @{Email=c_vjacobs@uni.example.com; DisplayName=VJacobs; Id=6;...
```

You could iterate over the `$relatedaccounts` using either the hashtable keys or the related groups (they are the same info)

```
foreach($key in $relatedaccounts.keys)
{
    write-host "Group containing IDs $key`n$('-'*30)"
    $relatedaccounts[$key] | out-host
}
```

or

```
foreach($idgroup in $related)
{
    write-host "Group containing IDs $idgroup`n$('-'*30)"
    $relatedaccounts[$idgroup] | out-host
}
```

They both output the same data, just the hashtable keys order is not guaranteed to be the same order as the related group list.

```
Group containing IDs 4,2
------------------------------

Email               DisplayName          Id AccountName   
-----               -----------          -- -----------   
rwilson@example.com Richard Wilson       2  richard.wilson
rwilson@example.com EM Engineering #1985 4  em_eng1985    


Group containing IDs 6,5
------------------------------

Email                     DisplayName     Id AccountName    
-----                     -----------     -- -----------    
vjacobs@example.com       Victoria Jacobs 5  victoria.jacobs
c_vjacobs@uni.example.com VJacobs         6  victoria.jacobs


Group containing IDs 3,8,7,1
------------------------------

Email                     DisplayName          Id AccountName     
-----                     -----------          -- -----------     
jsmith@example.com        EM Engineering #2013 3  em_eng2013      
i474@internal.example.com John Smith           7  i474            
i474@internal.example.com Interactive Console  8  interactive.i474
jsmith@example.com        John Smith           1  john.smith
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Doug! I'm ultimately needing to know how many groups we create when grouping related accounts together. Across my example data there are 3 distinct people. Victoria has 2 accounts, Richard has 2 accounts, and John Smith actually has 4 though there's some indirect relationships there. This should result in 3 groups.

The output I see in your answer is almost right except it hasn't put the accounts with IDs 7 and 8 into the same group as accounts with IDs 1 and 3.

Comment: Well looking at it, the display names should've matched. However I made an error in logic. After one's been joined it can no longer `-eq`. I'll update my answer soon

Comment: The output is spot on! I noticed though if I randomize the position of accounts in the  `AccountsList` array via `$accountList = $accountList | Get-Random -Count $accountList.Count` right before feeding it to `foreach` it will sometimes throw an exception. I did this because there's no real order to the actual data I have today, though I could certainly try to put it in some kind of order if needed.

Comment: Hmm I believe it has to do with i474 and interactive.i474 matching each other. Does your error go away no matter what the order as long as ID 7 is before ID 8?

Comment: Yeah it's matching two lines there. Is it going to be possible that the real accounts will have a simple display name that is also embedded in another's displayname?

Comment: Looks like I can get it to throw an exception if I move the very first account in `$accountList` to the bottom of the array. There are a bunch of cross-category relationships in our real account data. The provisioner/identity manager that created and managed these accounts is gone so whatever underlying correlation data it has is no more sadly. But yeah, we'll see a bunch of `Account A` is related to `Account B` because their email's match and `Account B` is related to `Account C` because their display names match. Way more exact matches on display names than substring matches

Comment: I updated my post, it's really long but there was so much to go over.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, seriously. In the edit, it should be `"There are {0} distinct users" -f $tracker.count ` as the last line right? Instead of `$related.count`?

Comment: Nope, tracker just ends up with useless data. Related contains the groups of related ids, 3 of them. Hence the reason we needed to post process the accounts based on those IDs.

Comment: If you look at tracker at the end of the script it contains 4 single accounts, just used for comparing info.

Comment: I may be missing something then, if I run related always produces count of 1 with a value `7,18` unless I include the hashtable randomizer before the line that converts to pscustomobject.

Comment: Here's a pastebin:
https://pastebin.pl/view/edb7eeda

Comment: Yeah me too. Hell I don't know, I'm near the point of giving up.